# Битрикс. Многосайтовость. Нет доступа к разделам сайта с поддомена

Tags: битрикс, поддомены

Организовал многосайтовость следующего вида:

```
site.ru - основной домен
m.site.ru - поддомен (мобильная версия сайта)
```

﻿Проблему рассмотрю на примере новостей:

В разделе **site.ru/news/** находится компонент news ﻿Список новостей и детальные страницы новости отображаются корректно, но при переходе по этим же ссылкам с поддомена (например **m.site.ru/news/news1**) открывается карта сайта. Как я понял - проблема с доступом.

Создал symlink для папки **news** ﻿и и она начала открываться с поддомена, но теперь не открываются сами новости (детальная страница элемента).
Мое предположение - это связано с тем, что папка news существует физически, а детальные страницы новостей формируются из настроек инфоблока и компонента.
Кто подскажет как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо никаких симлинков. В инфоблоке даете доступ, чтобы инфоблок был доступен обоим сайтам. В настройках путей для инфоблока, указываете правильные пути. На обоих сайтах создаете раздел news/ и кладете в news/index.php компонент, в котором настраиваете все для каждого сайта.